# How did 'less than' semantically shift to mean 'if not'?

Tags: etymology

> 1. [unless (conj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=unless)
>      mid-15c., earlier *onlesse*, from *(not) on lesse (than)* "(not) on a less compelling condition (than);" see [less](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=less&allowed_in_frame=0). The first syllable originally [on](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=on&allowed_in_frame=0), but the negative connotation and the lack of stress changed it to *un-*.
> 2. [à moins que](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_moins_que) = sauf si.
> 3. [a menos que](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_menos_que) means 'unless' in Spanish and Portuguese.
> 4. [a meno che](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_meno_che) means 'unless' in Italian.

The above substantiates the same semantic shift in at least 4 languages,
from  the  prepositional phrase

- a/à/un ← on (preposition) +
- **less (adverb)** +
- than (comparative preposition)

that semantically shifted to mean '**if not**'.

What semantic notions underlie this semantic shift from **less** to  **if not**?

Comment: I'm not familiar with diachronic semantics or historical development of English or the Romance languages, but from a common-sense point of view, I could use _less_ in place of _not_ for litotes. So I'd speculate that, if this usage gains prestige, it could gain currency and displace the original meaning...

Comment: By the way, sorry if my comment was less than helpful. (Sorry, I couldn't resist...)

Comment: This is unclear. Can you provide an introductory sentence explaining the situation?

Comment: Would you expect an explanation of 'less->not' be similar to one for 'but->not'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What underlying semantic notions connect 'less' to 'not'?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17459/what-underlying-semantic-notions-connect-less-to-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I’m leaving **unless** I get a pay rise.*
>
> *I'm leaving **on ye olde<sup>1</sup> lesse compelling condition than if** I get a payrise.*

I am no native speaker but this sounds fairly synonymous to me - me getting a payrise is a condition for me to not leave and anything less than that means I am leaving.

<sup>1</sup> Sorry, just could not resist.

Comment: Should this be a comment?

Comment: I believe it explains the shift from *on less* to *if not* quite clearly, so it is an answer:)